# Cannot deploy Java Adapter on IBM MobileFirst Platform 8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mfp

We have a java adapter that we are trying to deploy in IBM BFP 8.0. See error stack trace below:

```
[ERROR] logger.changeStateDeploymentException: FWLSE0321: State change failure. Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: User code thrown exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/http/impl/conn/CPool.setValidateAfterInactivity(I)V  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:181)  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:163)  at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:973)  at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:56)  at com.mypackage.adapter.XYZJavaAdapterResource.init(XYZJavaAdapterResource.java:52)  at com.mypackage.adapter.XYZJavaAdapterApplication.init(XYZJavaAdapterApplication.java:21)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)  at 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.531 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-05T18:28:03+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/204M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2018082311:deploy (default-cli) on project com.mypackage.XYZJavaAdapter: Unexpected response from http://somehost:9080/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/adapters -> [Help 1]



MFP version: 
Name: IBM MobileFirst Platform Server
Installation directory: /opt/IBM/MFPDEVENV/MobileFirst_Platform_Server
Translations: English (en)
Architecture: 64-bit

[Package]
Name: IBM® MobileFirst Platform Server (com.ibm.mobilefirst.foundation.server)
Version: 8.0.0.20170220_1811 (8.0.0.20170220_1811)

CLI VERSION:
MobileFirst Platform Foundation Command Line Interface (CLI): 8.0.0-2018040312
```

MFP console log: see below

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: User code thrown exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/http/impl/conn/CPool.setValidateAfterInactivity(I)V
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:181)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:973)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:56)

[10/26/18 8:36:24:686 HKT] 00013f2d .worklight.admin.configservice.datastore.ConfigServiceClient E Unable to delete configuration with id ADAPTER_CONTENT due to exception FWLSE3208E: An invalid status code "404" was returned. The response content is "{"reason":"configuration_not_found","details":"CNFSRVE115: configuration with id 'ADAPTER_CONTENT' for schema 'mfp_default_schema' with version '1.0' not found"}"
```

Can anyone help us on how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you adding something specifically in the pom.xml for Apache httpclient?

Comment: I can show you the pom.xml file if you need to take a look at it

Comment: Also, if there is any initialization code within your logic around the Apache httpclient, if you wrap it in try , catch block, does this go through? And what does your server logs show.

Comment: I dont think it will pass through that catch block since the error is in deployment of the adapter and not error in running it

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the server logs?

Comment: the errors are in the stack trace I posted above. Those are errors seen when the java adapter is deployed in MFP

Comment: This is from the CLI. I am asking if your MFP server logs show any errors

Comment: ok gotcha. I added the MFP console logs in my first post